# Wrapping an object with methods from another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Let's say I have a model called Article:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And then I have a class that is intended to add behavior to an article object (a decorator):

```
class ArticleDecorator

  def format_title
  end

end
```

If I wanted to extend behavior of an article object, I could make ArticleDecorator a module and then call article.extend(ArticleDecorator), but I'd prefer something like this:

```
article = ArticleDecorator.decorate(Article.top_articles.first) # for single object
```

or

```
articles = ArticleDecorator.decorate(Article.all) # for collection of objects
```

How would I go about implementing this decorate method?

Comment: PS: I am familiar with the draper gem, but do not want to use that implementation for the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/search.rb. It does something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly do you want from `decorate` method? Should it simply add some new methods to passed objects or it should automatically wrap methods of these objects with corresponding format methods? And why do you want `ArticleDecorator` to be a class and not just a module?

**Updated:**

Seems like solution from **nathanvda** is what you need, but I'd suggest a bit cleaner version:

```
module ArticleDecorator

  def format_title
    "#{title} [decorated]"  
  end

  def self.decorate(object_or_objects_to_decorate)
    object_or_objects_to_decorate.tap do |objects|
      Array(objects).each { |obj| obj.extend ArticleDecorator }
    end
  end

end
```

It does the same thing, but:

1. Avoids checking type of the arguments relying on `Kernel#Array` method.
2. Calls `Object#extend` directly (it's a public method so there's no need in invoking it through `send`).
3. `Object#extend` includes only instance methods so we can put them right in `ArticleDecorator` without wrapping them with another module.

Answer (score 1):

May I propose a solution which is not using Module mixins and thereby granting you more flexibility. For example, using a solution a bit more like the traditional GoF decorator, you can unwrap your Article (you can't remove a mixin if it is applied once) and it even allows you to exchange the wrapped Article for another one in runtime.

Here is my code:

```
class ArticleDecorator < BasicObject
  def self.[](instance_or_array)
    if instance_or_array.respond_to?(:to_a)
      instance_or_array.map {|instance| new(instance) }
    else
      new(instance_or_array)
    end
  end

  attr_accessor :wrapped_article

  def initialize(wrapped_article)
    @wrapped_article = wrapped_article
  end

  def format_title
    @wrapped_article.title.upcase
  end

  protected

  def method_missing(method, *arguments)
    @wrapped_article.method(method).call(*arguments)
  end
end
```

You can now extend a single Article by calling

```
extended_article = ArticleDecorator[article]
```

or multiple articles by calling

```
articles = [article_a, article_b]
extended_articles = ArticleDecorator[articles]
```

You can regain the original Article by calling

```
extended_article.wrapped_article
```

Or you can exchange the wrapped Article inside like this

```
extended_article = ArticleDecorator[article_a]

extended_article.format_title
# => "FIRST"

extended_article.wrapped_article = article_b

extended_article.format_title
# => "SECOND"
```

Because the ArticleDecorator extends the BasicObject class, which has almost no methods already defined, even things like #class and #object_id stay the same for the wrapped item:

```
article.object_id
# => 123

extended_article = ArticleDecorator[article]

extended_article.object_id
# => 123
```

Notice though that BasicObject exists only in Ruby 1.9 and above.

Comment: That will work, since Ruby follows TMTOWTDI, but it can be achieved with object.extend(module) and module.included(class)

Comment: @philpirozhkov how, if I may ask? Removing the module? Changing the undecorated object at runtime? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You'd extend the article class instance, call alias_method, and point it at whatever method you want (although it sounds like a module, not a class, at least right now). The new version gets the return value and processes it like normal.

In your case, sounds like you want to match up things like "format_.*" to their respective property getters.

Which part is tripping you up?

Comment: I clarified my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
module ArticleDecorator
  def format_title
    "Title: #{title}"
  end
end

article = Article.top_articles.first.extend(ArticleDecorator) # for single object
```

Should work fine.

```
articles = Article.all.extend(ArticleDecorator)
```

May also work depending on ActiveRecord support for extending a set of objects.

You may also consider using [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).